# Куда Room сохранаяет Database? В какой папке проекта?

Tags: android, база-данных, sqlite, room

Вот пример работы базой данных с помощью Room.

```
public enum Database {
I;

private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "mc_db";
private AppDatabase database;

public AppDatabase db() {
       if (this.database == null) {
           this.database = Room.databaseBuilder((Context)App.getInstance(), AppDatabase.class, DATABASE_NAME).allowMainThreadQueries().fallbackToDestructiveMigration().buil  d();
       }
       return this.database;
    }
}
```

Где находится файл `mc_db`? Как его достать из проекта?

Comment: Ну наверное там же где обычно? Sqlhelper сохраняет.. getDatabasePath("mc_db").getAbsolutePath()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Обычно лежит по адресу

```
/data/data/имя пакета/databases
```